# serializar um array e passar como parâmetro para model

Tags: c#, json

Minha Action:

```
 public JsonResult SalvarCadastro(ListaModelView model)
 {    }
```

Meu Model:

```
    public string Assunto { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    public List<ContatosEmailModelView> Lista { get; set; }
```

Meu Js: Os input's do form é Assunto e Mensagem. Lista esta fora do form em um Table:

```
var dados = $("#form-envio-manual-cadastro").serialize();
$("#lista tr").each(function () {
            var linha = [];
            var tableData = $(this).find('td');
            if (tableData.length > 0) {
                tableData.each(function () { linha.push($(this).text()); });
                lista.push({ Email: linha[0], Contato: linha[1] });
            }
        });
 var list = '';
        $.each(lista, function (key, value) {
            list += encodeURIComponent($.param(lista[key])) + ';';
        });

        dados += '&Lista={' + list + '}';
```

Ao chamar a action passando dados como parametro, não esta preenchendo a propriedade Lista, somente assunto e email. Como preencho uma propriedade do tipo List?

Comment: O resultado dados esta: "Titulo=&Assunto=&Mensagem=&NovoEmail=&Nome=&Matricula=&Lista={Email%3Dteste%2540email.com.br%26Contato%3DJuracildo%2BPereira;Email%3Dmaria%2540email.com%26Contato%3DMaria%2BTeixeira;}"

Comment: mas nesse resultado a lista está preenchida com os emails e nomes

Comment: Mas na action a propriedade Lista do Model fica count = 0

Comment: Se passar como string funciona?

Comment: Não entendi Wees. Passa string como?

Comment: no model vc esta passando como `list`, testa passar como `string`